# SSIS deployment on databases part of AAG

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

Experts, I have two databases, one is SSISDB, other is user database. Both of them are a part of Always on availability group. I need to give one user a permission to be able to deploy a package. How should I go about doing this. He already has a login and has a data reader access to both the databases. We are talking about SQL server 2016 EE here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1. Make the user a member of `ssis_admin` role which of course give more privilege than you intend to.

> This role provides full administrative access to the SSIS Catalog
>   database.

2. You can give permission at folder level under `integration services catalogs`.  Here you have a better control, but you have to do this for each folder.
   Details explained here: [SSIS Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/ssis-catalog#Permissions)